# Split values in a column in "is a date" or "NaT"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, train-test-split

I would like to find values in a column (`clear_date`) that do not correspond to a valid date. The date is formatted as `'%Y/%m/%d'`.

I've tried the following piece of code but, the resulting variable doesn't have any rows!

```py
x_test = dataset[dataset['clear_date'] == "NaT"].copy()
```

Here is a picture for reference:
[image]

Comment: what's the `dtype` of that column?

Comment: @PierreD datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `clear_date` column is already a proper datetime, then:

```
x_test = dataset.loc[dataset['clear_date'].isnull()].copy()
```

Otherwise, e.g. if it is a string:

```
x_test = dataset.loc[pd.to_date_time(dataset['clear_date']).isnull()].copy()
```

Comment: The ```clear_date``` column is already a datetime
The first code worked for me. Thanks :)